# JsPlumb connector lines and anchor as triangle fails

Tags: jquery, html, jsplumb

I'm using JsPlumb in my current project and I'm currently having 2 small problems that I hope someone can help me with.

```
var anEndpointDestination = {
    Connector: ["Straight"],
    anchor: ["Perimeter", { shape: "Diamond" }],
    endpoint: "Dot",
    maxConnections: -1,
    isSource: false,
    isTarget: true,
    anchor: [0.96, 0.2, 1, 0, 0, -25],
    paintStyle: { fillStyle: "blue" }
};
```

The first thing I cant make work correctly is, the `Connector line` between achors to go in a zig/zag path like in this [demo](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos/toolkit/flowchart-builder/index.html).

The second problem is that my `anchor` dont get the Diamond shape from `anchor: ["Perimeter", { shape: "Diamond" }]`

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the zig/zag path I believe you need to use the Flowchart connector. More info on that [here](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/connectors.html)